# Can I set two Column in CarouFredSel Slider at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caroufredsel

I'm using carouFredSel slider.
It's coming out 6 items at a time.
I want to set this 3row & 2Column (total 6 items) at a time.
How can I set this?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#main_new_area").carouFredSel({
    auto: 7500,
    width: "variable",
    height: "auto",
    circular: !1,
    scroll: {
      fx: "crossfade",
      duration: 500,
      easing: "linear"
    },
    items: {
      start: 6,
      visible: 6
    },
    pagination: ".new_pager",
    prev: ".new_prev",
    next: ".new_next"
  })
});
```

Comment: If you create a working example I'll try to help. This library is very old. You might consider to use other library such as [tiny-slider](https://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/demo/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. :D I'm so sad I have to use this library. It's already seted our system. I create a working example. Can you check this please?
I want to set this 3X2rows. So 6 items at a time.

https://codepen.io/denggoo/pen/LYNVrze

Comment: Something like that? https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/mdPJQeZ

Comment: Thank you!! I figure it out. you're a genious!! :D

Comment: Glad to hear :) You can post the answer here, maybe it will help to other people.